# Why does Processing think I'm passing an int into the color() function at the end of this code?

Tags: hashmap, casting, processing

Preface: I'm working with Processing and I've never used Java.

I have this Processing function, designed to find and return the most common color among the pixels of the current image that I'm working on.  the last line complains that "The method color(int) in the type PApplet is not applicable for the arguments (String)."  What's up?

```java
   color getModeColor() {
     HashMap colors = new HashMap();
     loadPixels();
     for (int i=0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
       if (colors.containsKey(hex(pixels[i]))) {
         colors.put(hex(pixels[i]), (Integer)colors.get(hex(pixels[i])) + 1);
       } else {
         colors.put(hex(pixels[i]),1);
       }
     }

     String highColor;
     int highColorCount = 0;

     Iterator i = colors.entrySet().iterator();
     while (i.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
       if ((Integer)me.getValue() > highColorCount) {
         highColorCount = (Integer)me.getValue();
         highColor = (String)me.getKey();
       }
     } 
     return color((highColor);
   }
```

The [Processing docs](http://www.processing.org/reference/HashMap.html) that I'm looking at are pretty sparse on the HashMap so I'm not really sure what's going on inside it, but I've been augmenting what's available there with [Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) they point to.  But I'm not really grokking what's happening with the types.  It looks like the key in the HashMap needs to be a string and the value needs to be an integer, but they come out as objects that I have to cast before using.  So I'm not sure whether that's causing this glitch.

Or maybe there's just a problem with color() but [the docs](http://www.processing.org/reference/color_.html) say that it'll take a hex value which is what I was trying to use as the key in the HashMap (where I'd rather just use the color itself).

Now that I've talked through this, I'm thinking that the color() function sees the hex value as an int but the hex() function converts a color to a string.  And I don't seem to be able to convert that string to an int.  I guess I could parse the substrings and reconstruct the color, but there must be some more elegant way to do this that I'm missing.  Should I just create a key-value-pair class that'll hold a color and a count and use an arraylist of those?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure it out, but I did work around it.  I'm just making my own string from the color components like:

```
 colors.put(red(pixels[i]) + "," + green(pixels[i]) + "," + blue(pixels[i]),1)
```

and then letting the function drop a color out like this:

```
     String[] colorConstituents = split(highColor, ",");
     return color(int(colorConstituents[0]), int(colorConstituents[1]), int(colorConstituents[2]));
```

This doesn't really seem like the best way to handle it -- if I'm messing with this long-term I guess I'll change it to use an arraylist of objects that hold the color and count, but this works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'll dig deeper into this, but an initial thought is to employ Java generics so that the compiler will complain about type issues (and you won't get runtime errors):

`HashMap<String,Integer> colors = new HashMap<String,Integer>();`

So the compiler will know that keys are Strings and elements are Integers. Thus, no casting will be necessary.